# MMC Snapin Error

Tags: tridion

We recently installed Tridon 2011 SP1. When I am trying trying to open the SDL Tridion Content Manager snapin, I receive an error

MMC could not create snap in.

Name : SDL Tridion Content Manager
CLSID:{5DB34C8F-}

Tried reinstalling the application, but still the error persists.

Can somebody help me, with the same

Comment: Haven't seen this one before. Are you using the same account that performed the install? Is it an administrator account? Any other error logged in the Windows Event Logs? Google searches on "MMC could not create snap in" points into UAC issues. Try "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Is the exact text of the error you receive?

Comment: @Nuno: I am using the same account who performed the install. Also tried using the Run As Admin option, but that failed too.

Comment: @bukubapi: Can you please specify full CLSID?

Comment: @Igor: ClSID:{5DB34C8F-57EE-40F0-83A7-35DDD87587CE}

Comment: @bukubapi: Can you please check if you have next registry entry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{5DB34C8F-57EE-40F0-83A7-35DDD87587CE} and that HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{5DB34C8F-57EE-40F0-83A7-35DDD87587CE}\InprocServer32\ (Default) value points to the right location? And that file specified in this location actually exists.

Comment: @Igor: Both the key and the file exist. The deafult value points to C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\config\cm_cnfg_cnsl.ocx

Comment: @bukubapi: just another thought, are you trying to open mmc snap-in by the same user, who performed installation?
Did you check this topic as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017972/content-manager-configuration-snap-in-could-not-read-configuration-item

Comment: @Igor: Its the same user who has intalled Tridion, trying to run the snap-in

Comment: @bukubapi: Can you please try to run next command line from 32-bit cmd? "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe c:\test.vbs"
where content of test.vbs is:
set obj = CreateObject("TDSMngtExtension.Configuration")

Comment: @Igor: Getting the following error "Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Unknown runtime error:". If I try to directly run the vbs, I get Active X component can't create object: 'TDSMngtExtension.Configuration'

Comment: @bukubapi: It seems that error was truncated during copying: "Unknown runtime error:", there is no error code of "Unknown error". Can you please double check, if it also shows error code or any additional error messages? As for error during direct execution, most probably it is because Windows tries to execute it in 64-bit, but the problem that TDSMngtExtension.Configuration is 32-bit COM component, which can't be created in 64-bit process.

Comment: @Igor: This the error I receive - c:\temp\test.vbs(2, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Unknown runtime error: 'CreateObject'

Comment: @bukubapi: hm... it is really hard to resolve the problem with such generic error. Can you please run procmon while executing this vbsciprt? Maybe it will reveal access problems in registry or file system.

Comment: @bukubapi: was you able to resolve this issue? Recently, I have seen similar error with configuration due to corrupted MSXML4 SP3 installation. To check that MSXML4 SP3 works correctly, you will need to create another vbscript with next content: Set obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0") and execute it with C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe. Also you can just try to re-install it (uninstall/install) to see if it will help.

Answer (score 10):

What OS are you using? 64-bit?
Most probably you are executing 64-bit mmc. You should execute 32-bit mmc by next command line: mmc -32.
You can read more about mmc 32-bit/64-bit here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa815172(v=vs.85).aspx.

The problem that Tridion snap-in is 32-bit COM component, which can't be created in 64-bit process.

If it won't help, can you please check event viewer for more detailed error message?

Comment: We are using 64 bit OS. I tried the 32 bit mmc as suggested, but it also failed. I don't see any error in the event viewer related to this. I looked for it under all event types. Any pointers